# Proper format to markup article author for Google rich snippets and HTML5

Tags: google-search, html5, rich-snippets, markup, hyperlink

The Google guideline [Author information in search results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1408986?hl=en) tells us that we need to use the following format to link to the article author:

```
<a href="[profile_url]?rel=author">Author</a>
```

However, HTML5 specification has another construction for that:

```
<a href="http://author's-domain.com" rel="author">Author</a>
```

So what option should we use on an HTML5 website? Maybe, something like that

```
<a href="[profile_url]?rel=author" rel="author">Author</a>
```

, which is proper in both specifications?

Answer (score 1):

Although their documentation doesn't say so, using the `rel` attribute is supported by Google, so both should work.

The 'in-URL' `?rel=` syntax exists for blog users, who may not have access to edit the page's HTML tags, but the HTML5 separate attribute version is more 'correct' so I'd recommend:

`<a href="[profile_url]" rel="author">Author</a>`